# Is there MemoryUnit in java?

Tags: java, memory

With java time we got `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit` with it constants like: `MILLIS`, `SECONDS`, `HOURS` etc. Is there something similar but for memory unit? For example somethin liek `MemoryUnit` with `BYTES`, `KB`, `MB` with easy conversion from each other?

Comment: [JScience](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/SI.html) seems to be able to handle metric system units well in general, and you could probably adapt something using it for memory without too much trouble.

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box memory unit, and the other answer covers how to do such things manually.

Comment: Contrary to time units, you can convert between (integral) memory units by using bit shifts, making it a lot easier to compute than time units (assuming a base of 1024 instead of 1000 as people usually do in CS). In order to convert from bytes to KB, use `bytes >> 10`, for bytes to MB use `bytes >> 20` and so on.